# Mostrar sólo la columna ID con Eloquent/Blade. Me muestra todos los datos

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Al hacer una consulta y querer mostrar mediante Blade solo la columna "id" me muestra toda la información estructurada. ¿Qué sucede? Sólo quiero que muestre: 1

La programación es la siguiente:

web.php:

```
Route::resource('preguntas/{modalidad}','PreguntaController');
```

preguntaController.php:

```
public function index($modalidad)
    {

        $pregunta=Pregunta::where('id','1')->get();
        return view('preguntas')
        ->with('modalidad',$pregunta);
    }
```

vista donde mostrar la información:

```
{{$modalidad}}
```

Resultado en la web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes también usar el método `select()` e indicarle que columna deseas que te retorne, por ejemplo quedando así

```
$pregunta=Pregunta::select('id')
                   ->where('id','1')
                   ->get();
```

Si requieres retornar mas de un valor, entonces le puedes pasar en forma de array los valores al método de este modo:

```
$pregunta=Pregunta::select('id', 'nombre', 'otraColumna')
                   ->where('id','1')
                   ->get();
```

De tal modo que al imprimirlo, hagas esto para mostrar todos los valores obtenidos

```
@foreach($pregunta as $p)
   {{ $p->id }}
   {{ $p->nombre }}
   {{ $p->otraColumna }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas usando la ID para buscar, no para filtrar lo datos que quieres, es decir te trae todos los datos del registro.

Entonces tu consulta:

```
$pregunta = Pregunta::where('id','1')->get();
```

con un "filtro" para obtener solo la ID, quedaría:

```
$pregunta = Pregunta::where('id','1')->pluck('id')->first();
```

o bien, dado que buscas usando la ID:

```
$pregunta = Pregunta::find(1)->pluck('id');
```

#### Explicación

Con **[pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)** filtras los campos que quieres obtener en la consulta, si solo quisieras *id*, *nombre* y *apellido* para una búsqueda determinada pondrías `pluck('id', 'nombre', 'apellido')`.
pluck() trabaja con colecciones, no es que sea propio de eloquent, aunque como obtienes una colección de resultados se suele añadir a las consultas. Si bien sería válido hacerlo así:

```
$pregunta = Pregunta::where('id','1')->first();
$id = $pregunta->pluck('id');
```

He cambiado el método **[get()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)** por **[first()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)** al final de la consulta, ya que el primero te devuelve todos los resultados que cumplen el criterio de búsqueda, estas buscando por ID con lo que solo vas a tener un resultado, **first()** te devuelve el primer registro que coincide y para el caso solo hay uno, esto es importante a la hora de *acceder a los datos*.

La última consulta que te puse, la búsqueda se hace con **[find()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)** pasando directamente la ID. Este método se usa cuando buscas el registro a partir de su ID.

Bueno y para finalizar, ¿sabes que tienes la ID de un registro y quieres obtener esa misma ID?
El unico caso que se me ocurre para hacer algo parecido es saber, si por ejemplo el registro existe, en cuyo caso basta con hacer un find y preguntar si te devuelve null o no:

```
if (is_null(Pregunta::find(1)) {
    // el registro con ID: 1 no existe en la tabla
}
```

Comment: Pensaba que se podría montar de tal manera que luego pueda imprimir según me interese si quiere ID pues {{$modalidad->id}} si quiero Pregunta {{$modalidad->pregunta}} si quiero Respuesta {{$modalidad->respuesta}}, etc. ¿Sería posible? Gracias Orici.

Comment: @r84 puedes hacer como dices, y acceder a cada dato que necesites. Para imprimir lo que te interese del registro, no lo filtres (usa solo el `find()`), o filtra para obtener los campos que esperas usar.